# Using Named Credentials with client_id and client_secret in url query params

Tags: apex, namedcredentials

This is more of an instructional post because I spent so long trying to find the answer on here I felt like there should be a more direct post toward people trying to do something similar to what I have been struggling with:

When hooking up to an external api from salesforce with encrypted data, using Named Credentials is the best route. However, the documentation doesn't explain how to access the username and password of said named credentials very well.

I have posted the syntax below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('callout:My_Named_Credential_Name/login_path'); //This tells salesforce which credential you are referencing
req.setMethod('POST'); 
String jsonBody ='client_id=' + '{!$Credential.Username}' + '&client_secret=' + '{!$Credential.Password}';
//Credential is a Keyword, NOT where you substitute the name of your credential
req.setBody(jsonBody);
Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
System.debug(res.getBody());
```

This should work for anyone that is trying to retrieve an access_token from an external API. The jsonBody will be positioned after the url as though it is query parameters.

If my Named credential url is: https://looker.randomDomainName.com:19999/api/3.0

The Url/Endpoint will come out to:
https://looker.randomDomainName.com:19999/api/3.0/login_path?client_id=your_Named_Credential_Username&client_secret=your_Named_Credential_Password

I hope this helps!

Comment: more over with the new External Credentials you don't have to use `username` and `password`. https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.nc_create_edit_custom_auth_ext_cred.htm&type=5